# Rotating a UIImageView results in it moving back to its Storyboard starting position

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, transform

This problem occurs when I perform transformations on my images. I can reposition a UIImageView by resetting its center using CGPointMake, but when I go to rotate it with a line like,

```
image1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([image1 transform],angle);
```

the UIImage moves back to its original position (the place where I put it in my StoryBoard editor).

This person has my exact problem in his post:
[Rotating uiimageview moves image back to original storyboard position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337065/rotating-uiimageview-moves-image-back-to-original-storyboard-position)

Comment: Probably because auto layout is fighting you. See my "essay" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757

Comment: Thanks for that info, now I understand what the matter is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to the File inspector in interface builder, and unticking "Use Auto Layout" seems to solve the problem, however constraints are turned off when one does this. It is a good temporary solution, however. The first comment under my question also has some great info on the matter.